# Need to refine Regex expression

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse out two airport codes. There may or may not be white space or characters between them.

Sample data:

```
DFW A LAX

DFWLAX

DFW 1 LAX

DFW  LAX
```

Here is the regex expression I am using:

```
@"^([A-Z]{3})\s?\w?\s?([A-Z]{3})"
```

I'm getting a match on the first three examples. The problem is that I'm not getting a match where there is only white space between the two, like in the fourth example.

Comment: what programming language are you using? Can you just subscript your line taking first 3 and last 3 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just let the section between the two airport codes be 0 or more chars, that should do the trick:

```
@"^([A-Z]{3}).*([A-Z]{3})$"
```

Comment: @Letseatlunch: yes I did. However, it's a simple enough regex to be sure that it works w/o trying.

Comment: My mistake this does actually match all the ones listed above